# how to store newly created objects and read its info on demand

Tags: php, object

I have a form that a user will enter their studentID,Name,Major etc. then use those info to fill up  'student' class to create a 'student' object.

Now, I want to store these objects somewhere, somehow, and I want to be able to pull them back to use its data. I've looked into 'object serialization' but not quite sure if this will fulfill my needs, as I don't fully understand how this thing works...any help would be great, thanks.

And, I don't want to create a database, at all. No Mysql is allowed for this little assignment of mine...

Comment: Typically data is stored....in a database.

Comment: If you want an 'orm' that does a lot of the database housekeeping for you and is 'easy' to learn to use, although still a few hours. I would have a look at 'redbeanphp'.

Answer (score 0):

You could serialize your object as is and persist it to disk, but what happens if you want to search for students based on some criteria?

Usually, a relational database is used and an ORM to map your PHP objects to a rdbms table

[Wikipedia has a list of ORM's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#PHP) and frameworks for PHP, If you want something more lightweight then managin a db server, at least look into Sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when storing serialize objects. You might loose the ability to do certain things like search records. And if you don't understand how they work then they might behave unexpectedly.

A better approach would be to store individual properties as rows in database tables and then fetch the data into objects. To do this you can use ORMs like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html) which will map objects to database tables and persist them. Or a simple database class using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) should fulfill your basic needs as well.